# Как скрыть мобильное меню после нажатия в нем на якорную ссылку?

Tags: wordpress

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery('.menu .sub-menu').prev().append('<i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i>');

    jQuery('.menu-mobile .sub-menu').prev().append('<i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i>');

    jQuery('.open-menu-btn').click(function(){
        jQuery(this).toggleClass('open-menu-btn-active');
        jQuery('.menu-mobile').toggleClass('menu-mobile-active')
    })

    jQuery('.search-btn').click(function (e) { 
        e.preventDefault();
        jQuery('.search-form-overlay').slideToggle();
        jQuery('.search-form-container').slideToggle();
        jQuery(this).toggleClass('active-search-btn');
    });
    jQuery('.search-form-overlay').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        jQuery('.search-form-overlay').slideUp();
        jQuery('.search-form-container').slideUp();
        jQuery('.search-btn').removeClass('active-search-btn');

    });

    jQuery('.languages').click(function(){
        jQuery('.languages-menu').slideToggle();
    })

    jQuery('.menu-mobile li a').click(function(){
        // e.preventDefault();
        if(jQuery(this).next().length != 0) {
            if(jQuery(this).next().is(':visible')) {
                jQuery(this).next().slideUp();
            } else {
                jQuery('.menu-mobile li ul').slideUp();
                jQuery(this).next().slideToggle();
            }
        }
    })
$('.menu-mobile').on('click', 'li', function() {
  $('.menu-mobile').addClass('menu_hidden').attr('style', '');
})

$('.menu_up_mob').click(function() {
  if($('.menu-mobile').hasClass('menu_hidden') && $(window).width <= 992) {
    $('.menu-mobile').removeClass('menu_hidden');
  }
  else {
    $('.menu-mobile').toggle();
  }
})
    window.onscroll = function() {
        var height = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
        if(jQuery('aside').length) {
            var asidePosition = jQuery('aside').offset().top;
            if (height >= asidePosition) {
                jQuery('aside').addClass('static');
            }
        }
    }
```

```html
<div class="menu-mobile-menu-container"><ul id="menu-mobile-menu" class="menu-mobile menu-mobile-active"><li id="menu-item-409" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-home current-menu-item page_item page-item-8 current_page_item menu-item-409"><a href="https://truegenealogist.com/" aria-current="page">Home</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-411" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-411"><a href="#">About US<i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i></a>
<ul class="sub-menu" style="display: block;">
    <li id="menu-item-1708" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1708"><a href="https://truegenealogist.com/about-us/">About Us</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-415" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-415"><a href="/about-us/#history">Our History</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-1654" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-1654"><a href="/about-us/#experts">Our Experts</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-416" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-416"><a href="/about-us/#tree">Our Tree</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-1655" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-1655"><a href="/about-us/#partners">Partners</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-1656" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1656"><a href="https://truegenealogist.com/contact-us/">Contact Us</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-1657" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-1657"><a target="_blank" rel="noopener" href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCHdIzQROXhnAIufTEwcJ63g">YouTube</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-1658" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-1658"><a href="#">How It Works<i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i></a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
    <li id="menu-item-1659" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1659"><a href="https://truegenealogist.com/how-it-works/">How It Works</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-1660" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-1660"><a href="/how-it-works/#familyresearch">Family Research</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-1661" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-1661"><a href="/how-it-works/#coaching">Genealogy Coaching</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-1662" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-1662"><a href="/how-it-works/#SpecialtiesandLocations">Specialties and Locations</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-1663" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1663"><a href="https://truegenealogist.com/dna/">DNA</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-1664" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-1664"><a href="#">Rates &amp; Fees<i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i></a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
    <li id="menu-item-1665" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1665"><a href="https://truegenealogist.com/rates-fees/">Rates &amp; Fees</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-1666" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-1666"><a href="/rates-fees/#prices">Prices</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-1667" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-1667"><a href="/rates-fees/#packages">Packages</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-1668" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-1668"><a href="/rates-fees/#Additionalservices">Additional Services</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-1669" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-1669"><a href="/rates-fees/#Promotions">Promotions</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-1670" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-1670"><a href="/rates-fees/#freeestimate">Free Estimate</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-1671" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-1671"><a href="/terms-conditions/#refundpolicy">Refund Policy</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-1672" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-1672"><a href="#">Success Stories<i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i></a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
    <li id="menu-item-1673" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1673"><a href="https://truegenealogist.com/success-stories/">Success Stories</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-1680" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1680"><a href="https://truegenealogist.com/history-of-the-yudkevich-family/">Yudkevich</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-1678" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1678"><a href="https://truegenealogist.com/history-of-the-brumer-family/">Brumer</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-1681" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1681"><a href="https://truegenealogist.com/the-rawicz-family-history/">Rawicz</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-1677" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1677"><a href="https://truegenealogist.com/history-of-the-bachan-family/">Bachan</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-1675" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1675"><a href="https://truegenealogist.com/genealogy-of-the-peskovsky-family/">Peskovsky</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-1674" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1674"><a href="https://truegenealogist.com/genealogy-of-the-falken-family/">Falken</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-1679" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1679"><a href="https://truegenealogist.com/history-of-the-nathan-family/">Nathan</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-1676" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1676"><a href="https://truegenealogist.com/history-of-the-abarbanel-family/">Abarbanel</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-1682" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-1682"><a href="/success-stories/#Testimonials"><span style="color: #FFF8ED;">Testimonials</span></a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-1683" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-1683"><a href="#">Resources<i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i></a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
    <li id="menu-item-1688" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1688"><a href="https://truegenealogist.com/resources/">Resources</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-1684" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-1684"><a href="/resources/#database">Database</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-1685" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-1685"><a href="/resources/#faq">FAQ</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-1686" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-1686"><a href="/resources/#archives">Archives</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-1687" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-1687"><a href="/resources/#usefullinks">Useful Links</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul></div>
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: когда в мобильной версии открываешь меню и кликаешь на якорную ссылку, страница прокручивается но меню не исчезает. нужно чтоб оно исчезало после клика на якорь. меню сделано в Wordpress. Просто в коде выводится на страницу, но сделано не через код

Comment: Это все понятно, но не то чтобы это зависело от самого WordPress. Это, скажем так, фронтенд фича.

Comment: какой код и куда можно вставить? я уже кучу всего перепробовал, ничего не помогло

Comment: @AlexMslv а что Вы пробовали? Это скорее к JavaScript относится, а не к WordPress. К тому же все зависит от того какая у Вас тема и так далее.

Comment: @Simon тема самописная. вот фрагмент Java по меню

Comment: @AlexMslv JavaScript) Java -- совсем другой язык) Добавьте в вопрос html код меню, который у Вас получается на выходе (имею ввиду из инспектора браузера скопируйте), CSS и JS который Вы привели в комментариях, чтобы другие могли на это посмотреть. Сделать это можно нажав на кнопку [edit] под вопросом.

Comment: @Simon добавил код

Comment: @AlexMslv jQuery из комментариев тоже добавьте, а то так же его невозможно читать

Comment: @Simon добавил. не знал как тут вставлять правильно